# Cakephp save inserting record instead of updating

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to follow the cakephp 'saving your data' 2x cookbook but I am stumped. My UserController has a function Patient. My table is patientinformation. Below is a snippet of the code that I am using to save:

```
if (isset($this->request->data['patientinformation'])) {

       $this->patientinformation->create();
       $this->request->data['patientinformation']['UserID']=$this->Auth->user('id');
       $this->request->data['patientinformation']['Name']=$this->Auth->user('Name');

        } 
        $this->patientinformation->id['patientinformation']['id'];
        if ($this->patientinformation->save($this->patientinformation->id)){
           $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your information has been saved.'));
           $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your information could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
```

What I am hoping to do is to update a record if the id exists. I am not able to save my form data. Please let me know if I need to put additional information here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> Are you sure your data saving in DB correctly???

This following line in your code doesn't make any sence:

```
$this->patientinformation->id['patientinformation']['id'];
```

Use this:

```
$this->patientinformation->id = $this->request->data['patientinformation']['id'];
```

---

In this section of your code `$this->patientinformation->save($this->patientinformation->id)` you are trying to save `ID`, but its completely incorrect way. You should save like following:

```
 $this->patientinformation->save($this->request->data['patientinformation']);
```

Comment: Thank you Manwal! It is saving now. Unfortunately it is still inserting a new row. I do not have a primary key on my table. Do I need to use one?

Comment: Great. @shred_the_red you can accept answer if you got what you needed.